# Pandas contains() method doesn't recognize '$'

Tags: python, pandas

I am removing rows from a dataframe that match exactly `$1` under a particular column.

I do this with

```
apts = apts[~apts.Price.str.contains('$1')]
```

This doesn't remove any rows. But I know I have rows with `$1` under the Price column.

For example, this returns true:

```
if str(apts.ix[8193]['Price']) == '$1':
    print('True')
```

Any idea whats going on here?

Comment: For clarification, it might be helpful if you provided a few rows of your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a metacharacter that has a special meaning. You need to escape it to match it literally. From [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) you can see it relies on regex.

```
apts = apts[~apts.Price.str.contains('\$1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Pandas `contains` method excepts a regular expression, in which case `$` is used to signify the end of a line.  You'll probably want to escape your `$` with a `\`, so your code would be `apts = apts[~apts.Price.str.contains('\$1')]`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to escaping the `'$'` with `'\$'`, it's important to know that you can turn regular expression use off with `regex=False`

Consider the sample dataframe `apts`

```
apts = pd.DataFrame(dict(Price=['2,000', '$1,000', '1000', '$14']))

    Price
0   2,000
1  $1,000
2    1000
3     $14
```

Then using `regex=False`

```
apts[apts.Price.str.contains('$', regex=False)]

   Price
0  2,000
2   1000
```